# Measure of boundary of inverse image of smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, and $u \in C^1(A)$. Given $C \geq 0$:

> Is it true that the (Lebesgue) measure of the boundary of the set $\{|u|\leq C\}$ is zero?

I know I should provide at least a try but I don't know where to start from. I reckon that boundaries of closed sets don't generally have measure $0$, but maybe the fact that $u$ is smooth could help.

Can you give me a hint on how to start proving the claim if true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a closed set $E\subset \mathbb R^n,$ there exists $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $f=0$ on $E$ and $u>0$ on $\mathbb R^n\setminus E.$ In this case $\{|u|\le 0\} = E.$ Since $E$ can have no interior but still have positive measure, we have a counterexample.

Comment: Why doesn't $E$ have an interior? A bump function that is $1$ on a closed open ball  $E$ if properly flipped could be $f$

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @warm_fish the statement is that $u$ can be chosen in such a way that $E$ has no interior. It does not mean this is true for every smooth $u$.